# How I can set deep link for my app and search it in google

Tags: android, deep-linking

I want set deep link in my app and when search it in my devices browser it can open my app. Here is my code :
In Mainfest.xml

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- handle website links -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="tannerperrien.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- handle app links -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="tannerperrien" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

When I used app test deep link from google play : [test deep link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manoj.dlt&hl=en) it can open my app but I can search it from my browser.
How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can check doc for deeplinking here. It has how to implement and how to test. http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html#testing-filters

Answer (score 0):

[According Google App Indexing for Android](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/index.html)

You should:

- [Enabling Deep Links for App Content](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)
- [Specifying App Content for Indexing](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/enabling-app-indexing.html)